# Compare a converted TreeSet from a String with another TreeSet Java 7

Tags: string, java-7, treeset

Using Java 7 I am looking for a way to compare a string that I converted to a TreeSet with another defined TreeSet.

Here is an example:

```
public static <T> Set<T> intersection(Set<T> setA, Set<T> setB) {
        Set<T> tmp = new TreeSet<T>();
        for (T x : setA)
          if (setB.contains(x))
            tmp.add(x);
        return tmp;
      } 

public static void main(String args[]) {

String str ="A, B, C, D";
Set<String> set3 = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(str));
TreeSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<String>();
TreeSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<String>();
set1.add("A");
set1.add("B");
set1.add("C");
set1.add("D");
set2.add("A");
set2.add("B");
set2.add("C");
set2.add("D");
System.out.println("Intersection: Set 1 & 2: " + intersection(set1, set2));
System.out.println("Intersection: Set 1 & 3: " + intersection(set1, set3));


 }
```

Comparing a set to another set that I used set.add to add its elments works as expected:

```
Intersection: Set 1 & 2: [A, B, C, D]
```

The issue that I can't get my head around is why I don't have a match when I compare a converted TreeSet from a String with another TreeSet.

```
Intersection: Set 1 & 3: []
```

But when I print set1 and set3 I find them to be exactly the same??

```
 System.out.println("set1: " + set1);
 System.out.println("set3: " + set3);

set1: [A, B, C, D]
set3: [A, B, C, D]
```

Then I tried looping through the string and added each element to the set but that didn't work either.

System.out.println("Intersection: (set1 - set3)" + intersection(set1, convertString2Set(str)));

```
private static Set convertString2Set(String line) {
          List<String> linesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line));
         Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
        for (String elme : linesList) {
            set.add(elme);
        }
        return set;
    }
```

Comment: look at the actual content and size of your set3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set3` in your code contains only one element: a string which is equal to "A, B, C, D". This string is not equal to either of four strings in `set1`, which are "A", "B', "C" and "D". The toString() representation of the two sets happens to be the same, but it does not mean that they have the same content.

`Arrays.asList()` on a `String` does not split anything; it will always create a single-element list. If you want to split a string into multiple substrings, use the `String.split()` method.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I have tried splitting the string then add it to the set and it's didn't work. So, how can I compare the content of string with the content of set

Comment: How exactly did you try splitting the string?

Comment: I have updated at the question on how I looped through to add each element to the set. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! When I searched for how to convert string to set, everyone answer I found uses Arrays.asList(). But after your explanation I believe that Array.asList() should not be used the way to convert string to a set if you are looking for a true set at the end. Hence my confusion at the beginning. Thanks again for your detailed answer.